# How to show byte representation of unicode string in Python

Tags: python, unicode, byte

Lets say I write the character "a" into a string via its unicode codepoint:

```
In [1]: var="\U00000041"
```

If I now look at the variable again it will display me the character and not the byte-representation:

```
In [1]: var
Out[1]: 'a'
```

How can I get Python to show me the byte-representation?

I know by using the ord() method I can get the codepoint of the character, but I want the option to have Python show me the byte-representation again.

How do I do that? I looked through all the internet;)

Best regards

Comment: What is "the byte representation"?

Comment: `var.encode().hex()` ?

Comment: do you mean binary representation of corresponding hex value?

Comment: Do you mean: `print("\\U{0:0>8x}".format(ord(var)))`?

Comment: ```a ="\U00000041" 
        for _c in a: 
        b= 'U+%04x' % ord(_c)
    print(b)
    >> U+0041```